# C fopen mode parameter

Tags: c, file, fopen

Why is the 'mode' paramter for `fopen` in C given by a string? It would make more sense (in my way of thinking) for it to be  a bitmask or the likes. The overhead a string necessitates is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: Has your program ever suffered a significant bottleneck caused by the parsing of the attribute string?

Comment: I would suspect the overhead of parsing that tiny string pales in comparison to the opening of the file itself.

Comment: Valid points but the reasoning behind it is still unanswered. Aside from that, would you rather parse a mode string argument if you had created the function? I'm curious as to why.

Comment: @Dayalrai, `fopen(f, "wb")` is not more readable than something like `fopen(f, FILE_WRITE | FILE_BINARY)`, his question makes sense to me.

Comment: [A closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31433959/827263) asks why it doesn't use an `enum`; the answer is that `fopen` predates `enum`. The sample implementation of `fopen` in K&R1 (1978) only looks at the first character of the mode string, which could be `'r'`, `'w'`, or `'a'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### C11 §7.21.5.3 The fopen function
>
> The argument `mode` points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is
>   open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.271)

In the footnote:

> 271) If the string begins with one of the above sequences, the implementation might choose to ignore the remaining characters, or it might use them to select different kinds of a file (some of which might not conform to the properties in 7.21.2

According to the C99 Rationale, the committee thinks an implementation may choose to use `mode` other than the flags:

> #### [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §7.19.5.3 The fopen function
>
> An implementation may choose to allow additional file specifications as part of the mode string argument. For instance,
>
> ```
> file1 = fopen(file1name, "wb,reclen=80");
> ```
>
> might be a reasonable extension on a system that provides record-oriented binary files and allows a programmer to specify record length.

GNU libc has an extension that allows `mode` contains `ccs=STRING`, see [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Opening-Streams)

Answer (score 1):

If it were a bitmask it would have been more limited to future expansion. The GNU C library already allows 10 different modes, and MSVC 15. Additionally they support the `,ccs=string` syntax which would not be possible with a bitmask