# Why "fopen" function does not use enumerations?

Tags: c, stdio

What is the reason to use a `const char*` for selecting the open mode instead of an `enum` like this:

```
enum open_mode {
        READ,
        READ_BINARY,
        WRITE,
        ...
};
```

It wouldn't be more simply to use an enum?

Comment: That might have been a design decision. You could may try to ask this in Programmer network also; you might have more luck there.

Comment: Holdover from early C which I think lacked enums.

Comment: A very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999459/c-fopen-mode-parameter

Comment: Another one (answers are mainly speculations): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519263/why-does-cs-fopen-take-a-const-char-as-its-second-argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C's "fopen" take a "const char \*" as its second argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519263/why-does-cs-fopen-take-a-const-char-as-its-second-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is most likely historical: function `fopen` has been around in the early K&R version of the language, while `enum` has been added to the language only for the ANSI standard.

By the time `enum`s were added the language has been in such widespread use that changing the signature of such important function was impractical.

Comment: Hmm, I thought K&R1 had enums. (My copy is at the office, and I'll check it later today; I'm adding this comment mostly as a reminder to myself.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Are you one of the lucky owners of the first edition of K&R? I've got only the second edition (I learned the language from a home-made Russian translation of the first edition, though). Wikipedia says that "In the years following the publication of K&R C, several features were added to the language, supported by compilers from AT&T (in particular PCC[19]) and some other vendors. These included: ... enumerated types" ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C)).

Comment: Yes, I first learned C from K&R1. I'll also check whether it mentions `fopen` (I know it has `<stdio.h>`). If it has `fopen` and not `enum`, you'll be able to remove the "most likely" from your answer.

Comment: K&R1 does *not* have `enum`. It does mention `fopen()`, and shows a sample implementation. (The implementation only checks the value of `*mode`, and permits `'r'`, `'w'`, or `'a'`, so there's no allowance for binary mode or for more than one character.)

Answer (score 4):

This is to provide freedom for implementations. For instance the implementation in [VC++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) has the possibility to select encoding and such: `fopen("test.xml", "wt+,ccs=UNICODE")`

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer.  Because before there were `enum`s, people usually used `int`s and `#define`d macro constants for the same purpose rather than using character strings.

Comment: Sure, but an implementation could add more elements to an `enum` type.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That wouldn't work (without introducing weird varargs) for variable stream attributes:  `"wb,reclen=80"` (an example from the C rationale).

Comment: @cremno: True, but the original author(s) of `fopen` might not have been concerned with that. In any case, [dasblinkenlight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31434115/827263) is correct; `fopen` predates `enum`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I agree that it answers _this_ question. However I've found [yet another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519263/why-does-cs-fopen-take-a-const-char-as-its-second-argument). It's more broad. A definitive answer is missing though.